# Boto3 Missing required column 'Key' error even when set

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to import a key to API gateway with the following code

```
import boto3, hashlib, random, csv

apigateway = boto3.client('apigateway')

apikey = 'test'

with open('/tmp/apikey.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    filewriter.writerow(['Name', 'Key', 'Enabled', 'usageplanIds'])
    filewriter.writerow(['testkey', apikey, 'TRUE', '963uwo'])

response = apigateway.import_api_keys(
    body='/tmp/apikey.csv',
    format='csv',
    failOnWarnings=False
)
```

However that gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 312, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 601, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.BadRequestException: An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ImportApiKeys operation: Missing required column 'Key'
```

I've also tried copying directly the examples given at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-key-file-format.html but still get the same error, even though Key is clearly set.

Here's my /tmp/apikey.csv

```
jonathan@ubuntu ~> cat /tmp/apikey.csv
Name,Key,Enabled,usageplanIds
testkey,test,TRUE,963uwo
jonathan@ubuntu ~>
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that you do not write binary lines and my interpreter does not like the `mode='wb'`, can you try `filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')` ?

Comment: didn't work, I've updated the question to include the csv file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have supplied `body='/tmp/apikey.csv`' but the [import_api_keys](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.import_api_keys) API expects body to be *bytes or a seekable file-like object*. You have incorrectly supplied a filename.